# Pure java in Android app : 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: android, javac

If I want to include a pure Java external library, should I compile it with a 32 or 64 bit javac ?

I would like my app, and so my external library, to be used with Android Gingerbread 2.3

Thank you

Comment: I dont think it has an impact. but you should be sure, the libraries you use in your library has to be exist in Android java. check Android 2.3 from, http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/

Answer (score 0):

Class files produced by any java compiler are platform independent. Note, that not all of the java SE packages are present in Android. Also, Java 8 language features are not yet supported in Android (Part of them will be available in Android N).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use java 1.6 in Gingerbread 2.3
you can't use java 1.7 new api
in old devices that running Gingerbread 2.3 the ARM chips are  32-bit
so I think it is prefer to use **32 bit**.

to develop for new version 
you can use java 7 features in KitKat and newer 
and can some of java 8 api features in N preview